# Copy a file into a folder and all subfolders

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a folder 'A' which as 2 subfolders 'A-1' & 'A-2' and 'A-1' has 2 more sub folders 'A-1-1' and 'A-1-2' under it.

I would like to copy a file in all these folders.
Below is my powershell script.The problem is the file gets copied to some folders& for other folders I get a 'path not found error' Can you please suggest me what I can do to make it work ?

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\DestinationFolder\A\ -Directory -Recurse
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Filetocopy\abc.txt" -Destination "C:\DestinationFolder\A\$($folder.name)" -Recurse
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use this:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\DestinationFolder\A\ -Directory -Recurse

foreach ($folder in $folders) 
{
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Filetocopy\abc.txt" -Destination $folder.fullname
}
```

Comment: The select on the first line is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\DestinationFolder\A -Directory -Recurse | Copy-Item "C:\Filetocopy\123.csv" -Destination {$_.fullname}
```

Short version for no purist :

```
gci C:\DestinationFolder\A -Dir -Rec | cpi "C:\Filetocopy\123.csv" -D {$_.fullname}
```